# How to design a add new entry screen like in the Health app?

Tags: ios, user-interface, storyboard

I'm creating my first app and I wanted to design an "add a new item" modal like in the health app:
[image]

Here I have three questions:

1. How the 3 input fields are designed that you see the hint all the time on the left and the imput on the right? Is this just one field?
2. Are this 3 fields usually stored in a tableView?
3. Is the entry for the Date a special keyboard type or a DatePicker?

Comment: that looks like a tableview with a custom cell which has a label on the left and an input field on the right. the picker is a UIDatePicker

Comment: Please post this as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview) with a custom cell which has a UILabel on the left and an input field on the right. The picker is a [UIDatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker)